# Node.js - Is it better to minify HTML files as a post-build step or at runtime?

Tags: node.js, express, minify

I have a nodejs site built using express which we are trying to optimise. We have a layout.html file with a {{{body}}} token and several other html files which are merged into layout.html at runtime by the express rendering engine.

We would like to minify the html files as a post-build operation but it is failing because we have invalid markup in layout.html (the markup *is* valid after {{{body}}} has been replaced).

---

**Developer A**: Would like to fix the markup so we can minify post-build, partly because it makes working with the layout file easier in future, and partly because they believe we will get more of a performance benefit if we avoid the penalty of the web server CPU doing the minification at runtime.

**Developer B**: Says we should minify at runtime rather than fix the markup, and that we won't incur a penalty for doing so. They also believe minifying post-build will cause problems with express' rendering engine at runtime.

---

I don't know the tech well enough to know who is right and would welcome answers from experts in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Get minification done with tokens, it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for a critique of the two approaches rather than a third option.